# What's the difference between the assignment operator vs equal operator in C

Tags: c

```
int main(){

   int x = 5580, y = 55098;

   printf( "%d\n", y = x);

   return 0;

}
```

Why does this print the value of y?  I thought the value of x was being assigned to y but thats not the case.

Comment: I do not see a close relation between the title and the question in the body. The "equal operator" (assuming you mean `==`) does not occur.

Comment: It should print the value of `x`, i.e. `5580`,  and it actually does.

Comment: Tried, output: 5580. Did you mean "value of y after it got assigned the value of x"?

Comment: Are you aware that the value of an assignment statement is the assigned value? In contrast to an equality comparison (`y==x`), which is 0 for false or not 0 for true.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p3), an assignment expression evaluates to the valueof the left operand *after* assignment:

> **6.5.16 Assignment operators**
>
> (3) An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by
>   the left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left
>   operand after the assignment

So `y=x` in `printf( "%d\n", y = x)` first lets `y` take on the value of `x`, and then evaluates to the (newly assigned) value of `y`. So the output of the `printf`-statement will be `5580`, i.e. the value of `x`, which is the new value of `y`.

Comment: This question is a good opportunity to teach that, in C, the value of expressions are the “main” effect and that some expressions have side effects. In `y = x`, setting `y` to the value of `x` is actually the side effect, although it is of course the predominant use. Although this might seem like a technical point, it teaches learners how to think about C—and hence how to think about other expressions with side effects, and then to think about the rules about side effects and sequence points, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior in C and other languages. Your title of the question also is not worded very well. The assignment operator "is" the equal operator, and that is exactly what you are using. You might be getting confused by the order of operations in C. On your `printf` line, the expression `y = x` happens first, and the resulting value (`y`) is used as a parameter in your `printf` function, which is why you see the value of `y` printed. This is one of the fundamentals of C. I would recommend reading up on C syntax.